# PyDev under both Aptana and Eclipse very slow on a particular .py file

Tags: eclipse, sqlalchemy, pydev

This issue just started, last week I had no issues with the particular source file.
I'm using SQLAlchemy and Geoalchemy and the particular block of code that triggers Eclipse and Aptana to start pegging the cpu while simply editing the file is:

```
obsRecs = db.session.query(multi_obs)\
.join(sensor,sensor.row_id == multi_obs.sensor_id)\
.join(platform,platform.row_id == sensor.platform_id)\
.join(m_type,m_type.row_id == multi_obs.m_type_id)\
.join(m_scalar_type,m_scalar_type.row_id == m_type.m_scalar_type_id)\
.join(obs_type,obs_type.row_id == m_scalar_type.obs_type_id)\
.join(uom_type,uom_type.row_id == m_scalar_type.uom_type_id)\
.filter(multi_obs.m_date > dateOffset)\
.filter(multi_obs.m_type_id.in_(mTypes))\
.filter(multi_obs.d_top_of_hour == 1)\
.filter(platform.active < 3)\
.filter(platform.the_geom.within(WKTSpatialElement(bboxPoly, -1)))\
.order_by(platform.row_id)\
.all()
```

As soon as I start editing anything in that block, the issue occurs. I've cut out that bit of code and edited other areas in the file, and I have no problems. I've edited other python files with no problems as well. At first I thought there was some issue with code completion, so I turned that off and still get the issue.

I was using Eclipse Indigo and if I did not Force Quit the app, an out of memory Java error would get thrown. In Aptana the cpu spikes, then will go back to an idle usage, then spike again if I started editing again.

My setup:
OS X Lion
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)
i7 Quad core, 8Gb RAM

I thought the issue may have been triggered by the latest java update from Apple, so I rolled back the entire machine via Time Machine to a pre-update state and still have the issue.

I'd appreciate any pointers, I am at the point of trying to find a non-PyDev based solution.

**Edit**
Allowing Eclipse to run until erroring out, Console.App does show the following:

```
8/1/12 9:14:01.114 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse: Exception in thread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" Exception in thread "Poller SunPKCS11-Darwin" 
8/1/12 9:14:01.114 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
8/1/12 9:14:01.114 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetSlotInfo(Native Method)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.initToken(SunPKCS11.java:767)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.access$100(SunPKCS11.java:42)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$TokenPoller.run(SunPKCS11.java:700)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:45)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:103)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.ThreadPoolFactoryImpl.execute0(ThreadPoolFactoryImpl.java:94)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.timer.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:110)
8/1/12 9:14:01.115 PM [0x0-0x182182].org.eclipse.eclipse:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**Edit 2**

Grabbed the Oracle JDK, set the system to use it. Same issue.

**EDIT 3**

Similar problem is still occurring after a restore from backups. This issue must have been lurking and the code block managed to be just right to trigger it. Code completion engine is still prime suspect.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem but for a different, long query. I tried disabling auto-complete, tried the `-clean` thing, no luck.

To fix, I waited for the memory leak to explode and used `jmap.exe` to dump the heap. I then ran Eclipse Memory Analyzer to see where my memory was going, the screenshot is attached below. There was something about `com.python.pydev.refactoring.markoccurrences.MarkOccurrencesJob` in the job, so I disabled that option in Preferences->Pydev->Editor.

Ever since I did that Eclipse is a speed demon and no more crashing.  Someone with some street cred should post this as a bug at pydev.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had some success solving Eclipse insanity by starting with a clean workspace.

It's kind of a shot in the dark, but try the following one by one:

1. Start eclipse with the `-clean` option and the existing workspace.
2. If the above does not work, try editing the same file in a new workspace.

If you look in the Console.app, when editing the file, do you seen any relevant log messages ?

Does the Error Log View inside eclipse throw up any error messages when you try to edit the file in Aptana ?

**Update**

I just tried reproducing this in Eclipse Juno on Window 7 64 Bit and no problems with it:

[image]

I think it might be a time taking exercise, but would it be possible for you to upgrade to Eclipse Juno ?

Comment: Starting with the -clean switch didn't make a difference. New workspace did not make a difference either. Looking in the Console.App, I don't see anything that looks like a suspicious error. It's quite strange, anything else in that file does not trigger the problems. I noticed when I click in one of the statements, the CPU spikes and the memory consumptions doubles from ~350Mb to ~700Mb.

Comment: Interesting. This is kind of a shot in the dark, but I remember having performance problems with Older versions of eclipse with Code Folding enabled. Would code folding be applicable to PyDev ? If so try disabling it and see whether it helps ?

Comment: The problem is definitely with Code Completion or some part there of. I created a new file, copied just that block of code, brought over the imports for those objects and can reproduce the issue. If I get rid of the imports, there is no issue. Strange indeed.

Comment: Am trying to replicate the issue on Eclipse Juno, Windows 7(64 Bit) as we speak. Will report back in a bit.

Comment: Scratch that last post, regardless of whether the imports are there are not, the issue will occur.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with Juno. It does not happen immediately, however as I click around on parts in the statements, it will occur.

Answer (score 0):

For me that appears like a bug in the PyDev type inference engine... (could be looping until an out of memory error occurs). Just with that subset of your code I was not able to reproduce it here (i.e.: installing sqlalchemy and geoalchemy, creating a project with that file as a source file and working with the file did all work properly).

So, ideally, please create a project where that can be reproduced and create a bug report attaching that project (See: http://pydev.org/about.html for details on where to create the bug report). Also, please provide a link here in stack overflow as a reference.

Now, having said that, it may be that it's only some memory spike which would work later on (if that was the case, you could try raising the -Xmx flag in Eclipse.ini to something bigger -- although if you're in 32 bit java/Eclipse, that value should probably not be higher than 600m - 700m). Still, even if that's the case, please consider reporting that as a bug related to having too much memory used in that use-case (but please provide a project as a scenario on how to reproduce that).

Comment: Fabio, it does create an out of memory error. It seems like the issue must be something with my setup, however I am just not sure what. As I stated in my initial post, this just started occuring with this file within the last couple of days. I need to test with some other files to verify it is solely with this particular file/code block.

Comment: Checking the -Xmx flag, mine is current -Xmx512m.

Comment: 512m should be Ok... my guess is that some aspect of your code is making the type inference engine loop (i.e.: when mark occurrences, code analysis or code-completion is triggered), but it's hard to track it down without having a reproducible test case... Ideally you can make a reproducible test case and report a bug. Another option if you're inclined would be getting the Eclipse SDK, the PyDev source code (http://www.pydev.org/developers.html) and run it under the debugger to see what may be the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Again I too ran into this problem. I followed all the usual advice about memory settings, disabling code completion etc.

I was running Eclipse 4.2 on Mountain Lion. I tried upgrading to 4.3 and even tried the 4.3 32 bit version. nothing was working.

I casually noticed that one Python module in particular was the cause of my troubles, which ultimately resulted in my solution.

I have not gone into the why but the problem was with SQLAlchemy. I should qualify this and say that the problem was a very large Python module with many and long SQLAlchemy queries there in.

I split the SQLAlchemy queries into separate Python modules, which I did not like doing and that solved the problem. In this instance I would rather that Eclipse worked than having all my code in one module.